# Gathering information from database and showing it in the same view using jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, treeview

I am using asp.net mvc the develop the application. I have a view which should contain a treeview at left pane and the right pane should show the details on the node item selected in the treeview. The left pane table represents the treeview structure and right pane contains the details of selected item which should be taken from the database.

[image]

I have the treeview structure build, also using jquery am able to get the id of the selected item. I need to gather the item details and display it in the right pane.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're after a quick solution (if the page is fairly static), you could load all the information on the page and hide/show on click.

A quick solution

```
$('#item1').click(function () {
  hideAll(); //Hide 
  $('#item1details').show();
}
//#item2 etc..

function hideAll() {
  $('#item1details, item2details ... ').hide();
}
```

You could make your javascript a bit more elegant by selecting the index of the item and applying it your selector.

A more detailed solution would be to use an ajax get to retrieve the relevant information from the database and populate your detail view.

```
$.get('/controller/GetDetails', { index: index }, function (retHtml) {
   $('#itemdetail').append(retHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to post id to the action

```
 $.post("YourController/ItemDetails", { Id: selectedid },
     function(data) {
       $('#leftPane').html(data);
     });
```

In you controller

```
    public ActionResult ItemDetails(int Id)
    {
        // get yor item model by using the Id

      return View(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi
the basic tutorial will give you enough start from

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs

i belive this might be exactly what you are looking for

p